# gitlab giving users code download rights but no rights to see project

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way in gitlab to disable a project from showing up as a project if the user only has guest level privileges?

To clarify and add a little more detail.

I have added the ability for guest to download code but removed pretty much every privellege regarding actually using gitlab to look at the project. Which means that if the project shows up as a project to the user and they click on it gitlab returns an error. I would much rather gitlab not show the project at if the user has guest level access.

We use git submodules in our projects and we need to be able to give people the ability to clone a repo and all it submodules without giving everyone access to browse and find every project that can be a submodule or making projects public.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not. But feel fee to create a PR which add's this functionality